# On equivalences of trigonometric inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> **This question is in error.** (The source had a typo. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3213371/409).)

Let $a$ be a real positive number.
\begin{align}
\text{(I)}&   & a &> \frac{\sin(y_1(a))}{y_1(a)} & &\text{where $y_1(a)$ is the unique root of}& y &= a \cot(y) ~~\text{in}~~ (0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \\
\text{(II)}&  & a &>\xi & &\text{where $~~~\xi~\,~~$ is the unique root of}& \xi^2 &= \cos(\xi)  \quad\text{in}~~ (0,\frac{\pi}{2})
\end{align}

I have read that the two statements are equivalent, i.e. (I)$\iff$(II).
Does anyone have any hint how to prove this equivalence?

Comment: Is there a typo? I think for inequality (I) the defining equation for $y_1(a)$ should be $y = a \tan y$. That way things work out trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have eventually found out there was a typo in the book where I read this claim. The correct statement which can be proved is the following.

Let $a$ be a real positive number.
\begin{align}
\text{(I)}&   & a &> \frac{\sin(y_1(a))}{y_1(a)} & &\text{where $y_1(a)$ is the unique root of}& y &= a \cot(y) ~~\text{in}~~ (0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \\
\text{(II)}&  & a &>\frac{\sin\xi}{\xi} & &\text{where $~~~\xi~\,~~$ is the unique root of}& \xi^2 &= \cos(\xi)  \quad\text{in}~~ (0,\frac{\pi}{2})
\end{align}

The statement in the question is not true.